# need a regex to replace func_1(func_2(a,b)) as func_1_func_2(a,b)

Tags: regex, oracle, plsql

Would be great if someone can help me with below requirements

```
regex_replace(source,search_pattern,replace_pattern)
```

1)

```
Input :func_1(func_2(a,b))

output :func_1_func_2(a,b)
```

2)

```
func_1(func_2())

output :func_1_func_2()
```

3)

```
func_1(func_2()) + 3

output :func_1_func_2() + 3
```

4)

```
func_1(func_2()) + func_1(func_3()) 

output :func_1_func_2() + func_1_func_3()
```

Tried

```
select REGEXP_REPLACE('func_1(func_2(a,b))','func_1\(','func_1_') from dual ;
```

got
`func_1_func_2(a,b))` .

there is an extra ) in the end

also in the above cases `func_1` has only 5 possible values

Comment: Please edit the post to add the programming language tag; also, include what you have tried so far..

Answer (score 1):

Regex: `(\w+)(\()([\w(),]+)(\))`

Replace with: `\1_\3`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/AdG9rg/2)

Answer (score 0):

Try this pattern. It works for all of your examples. Hopefully it should work for others that you have not shown.

```
select REGEXP_REPLACE(s,'(func_.)\((func_.\(.*?\))\)','\1_\2') from t ;
```

[image]

[**Dbfiddle demo**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=cbe0c0d54642e13552671739bdf19494)